# Filter a record from a row from SQL Server table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a table with a column that contains data like this:

```
<E><A>a</A><B>b</B><C>c</C></E>
```

I have created a new table and now I need to insert each tag value into separate column of new table. I am very new to SQL and not sure how to perform this.

In the end, the data should look like this:

```
Column names    A | B | C  
Row             a | b | c
```

Could you please provide any pointer to solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this can help you:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    id int,
    xmlBody xml
);

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1, '<E><A>a</A><B>b</B><C>c</C></E>');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (2, '<E><A>a1</A><B>b1</B><C>c1</C></E>');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (2, '<E><A>a2</A><B>b2</B><C>c2</C></E>');

SELECT 
    xmlBody.value('(/E/A)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as A,
    xmlBody.value('(/E/B)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as B,
    xmlBody.value('(/E/C)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as C
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Hi, <E><A>a</A><B>b</B><C>c</C></E> this is present under one column name of a table. What shall I use in this case. Thanks

Comment: Just instead of xmlBody column name in my answer use name of your column.

Comment: data in that column is very long. WIll it be good to use that whole data in CAST function each time. Basically it would be good if we have it dynamic. Any help on that please. Thanks

Comment: If data is formatted like this, probably column type is already XML, if it is not you can easily convert with statement CAST(yourColumn as xml).

Comment: Sorry. Due to newbie in SQL I am not able to catch your statement. Could you please show it in answer if possible, Thanks

Comment: @Nilesh you have an example in the answer.

Comment: can you please help in converting the value as well. I am checking on google but not getting answer. Like I need to do like this -     xmlBody.value('(/E/A)[1]', 'CONVERT(DATETIME,columnName,121)') as A, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use xmlBody.value('(/E/A)[1]', 'datetime').